# Conditional variable assignment with numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm migrating my Python based engine to Numpy in hopes of better performance. Previously I used my own vector3 class: With it I could use use conditional variable assignments in the following form, with `settings["size"]` being the provided array if present in the settings dictionary otherwise `0,0,0` as the fallback.

```
self.size = "size" in settings and settings["size"] or vec3(0, 0, 0)
```

Now I am instead using:

```
self.size = "size" in settings and settings["size"] or np.array([0, 0, 0])
```

But this introduces a new error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

What is the correct way of doing inline conditional assignments with numpy arrays, where it's checked whether the value exists and a default is set is not?

Comment: "What is the correct way of doing inline conditional assignments with numpy arrays" - the same way as with any other objects: using the proper ternary conditional operator added to the language [in Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions), released in 2006, rather than the legacy and/or hack - see the first linked duplicate. The error occurs because Numpy arrays can't be used with `or` like that; see the second linked duplicate, expecially my answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  The and/or thing is dangerous because of the way Python handles the types, so this should work:

```
self.size = settings['size'] if "size" in settings else np.array([0,0,0])
```

Or:

```
self.size = settings.get('size',np.array([0,0,0])
```

Or even:

```
self.size = settings.get('size',np.zeros(3))
```

Comment: Looks good and much better than what I was doing, thanks.